# qSort to sort structures

Tags: c, sorting, structure, qsort

I'm trying to sort the following structure:

```
typedef struct thing {
    char *text;
    int count;
} *Item;
```

I'm creating an additional vector to sort the structures like this:

```
Item items[nr_of_items];

... here is a loop to place the items inside the vector items ...

qsort(items, nr_of_items, sizeof(Item), cmpItem);
```

And here is the compare function:

```
int cmpItem(const void *a, const void *b) {

  const Item item_a = (const Item)a;
  const Item item_b = (const Item)b;

  /* Return 1 or -1 if members are not equal */
  if (item_a->count > item_b->count) return 1;
  if (item_a->count < item_b->count) return -1;

  /* Return 1 or -1 if members are not equal */
  if ( strcmp ( item_a->text, item_b->text ) > 0 ) return 1;
  if ( strcmp ( item_a->text, item_b->text ) < 0 ) return -1;

  /* Return 0 if both members are equal in both structures */
  return 0;

}
```

The vector is being correctly created, however it isn't being sorted. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are probably a lot of duplicates of this one.  You need `const Item item_a = *(const Item *)a`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that before but I always get a segmentation fault error. Maybe it's because I have typedef my structure to *Item?

Comment: It should work if `Item` is typedeffed as a pointer, *if* all the pointers in the original `items` array are set up correctly.  Does `items[]` indeed contain `nr_of_items` number of valid pointers to `struct thing`? (and what about the allocation of the `text` pointers, are you sure those are okay, too?)

Answer (score 3):

The `compar` callback function of `qsort` receive two arguments that point to the objects being compared, that is pointers to two elements in the `items` array. That means, both `a` and `b` are pointers to `Item`, not `Item` itself. You need change to this:

```
const Item *pa = a;
const Item *pb = b;
const Item item_a = *pa;
const Item item_b = *pb;
```